# English dictionary API that allows wild card look up

Tags: dictionary, wildcard

I would like to find a dictionary with API that allows me to look up words that match a wild card and a particular part of speech (noun/verb/adjective...), for example, give me a list of verbs that end with "ize".

I've been looking at Wordnet but looks like it doesn't support wildcard look up.

Thanks.

Comment: You could use the SQL version of Wordnet with a LIKE search on the word.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose you are talking about this http://wnsql.sourceforge.net/ and after some research I figured it would need this http://wnsqlbuilder.sourceforge.net/ as well. I will start working on it but I would still prefer a more straight-forward solution (i.e. another dictionary/API that has direct support for SQL or that kind of look up) if at all available.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this in two steps:

1. From a big list of words (English dictionary, such as [Peter Norvig's word list](http://norvig.com/ngrams/word.list)) you can subset only those words that match your wildcards.
2. For those matching words, test their parts-of-speech to see if they match your target (Verbs, nouns etc.)

In my example, I use a very small list of words:
(Python)

```
import nltk
import re

#replace with English dictionary
#Using a small list of words for illustration
lst = ['swim', 'while', 'greet', 'prize', 'jeopardize', 'quartz', 'zebra']

def subset_words_by_wildcard(wordlist, pattern):
    matchingwords = []
    for w in wordlist:
        if re.search(pattern, w):
            matchingwords.append(w)
    return matchingwords

def subset_words_by_pos(words, pos):
    wpos = nltk.pos_tag(words)
    for w,p in wpos:
        if p == pos:
            print w,p


if __name__ == '__main__':

    pattern = r'ize$'
    #target_pos = "NN" 
    target_pos = "VBP"

    mlist = subset_words_by_wildcard(lst, pattern)
    subset_words_by_pos(mlist, target_pos)
```

Running this produces:

`>>> jeopardize VBP`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explaination and sample code. However I decided to go the SQL route as it is more flexible and more efficient in terms of performance.

Comment: Sure. Whatever suits you best.